# static_pointer_cast with custom delete

Tags: c++, casting

I have this function which adds any class that derives from `Object` to a container.

```
template<class T> void registerObject(T& object) {
    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<T>(&object, [](T*){});
    std::shared_ptr<Object> op = std::static_pointer_cast<Object>(sp);
    objects_.push_back(op);
}
```

What happens in the `static_pointer_cast` that makes the custom delete method still valid for the new pointer?

I ask because doesn't the lambda evaluate to taking the derived type? But then the casted pointer will pass a `Object*` to that lambda? So isn't some "upcasting" happening when the custom delete is called? Which I thought was impossible because you can't guarantee that the base type is the derived type?

Comment: Wait a second. You are creating a vector of `shared_ptr`, where every `shared_ptr` has an empty deleter?

Comment: @pmr If the object is added through this method, yes. I have another method `void registerObject(std::shared_ptr<Object>)`. This one is to stop it trying to delete things that shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @rhalbersma doesn't look like a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @johannes: sorry, I blind-voted. should have looked first. i'm not sure what your point is but now after looking i'm not entirely sure of duplicate'ness either, so. i'll answer ze question then. hrmpf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how a `boost::shared_ptr` works:

- Each instance (in your code) has a pointer to a shared single *control block* for the pointee.
- At least conceptually it also has a raw pointer to the pointee, of the type implied by this instance. Due to the type this raw pointer can be adjusted, not the same bitpattern as the original pointee pointer.
- The control block contains the original raw pointee pointer, a reference count, and the original deleter func. The deleter func is called (when and if it is) with the original raw pointee pointer as argument.

When you cast you only affect the new `shared_ptr` instance, not the control block that it points to. So, the information needed for deletion is not affected at all. Even though the instance's (conceptual) typed pointee pointer can be affected.

Comment: I'm using the C++11 `shared_ptr` which I think is the same? Looks like I will have to do some more reading up on `shared_ptr`s :) Thank you.